# Can I create HTML form fields with fixed positions using Orbeon forms?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, orbeon

In Orbeon forms, is it possible to position input fields at a specific X, Y location, relative to a background image?

I have an existing paper form which covers a complete page.
I want to use the scanned form image as a background and then place input fields over the background in specific locations.

I know this is possible with Adobe Acrobat, but I am looking for a web-based Open Source alternative.

Currently I am using html forms using code like the following:

```
<input name="current_user" id="current_user" type="text" class="noborder"
       style="position:absolute; left:90px; top:15px; 
              width:270px; height:19px;"  oscarDB=current_user>
```

The position:absolute; left:90px; top:15px; places the input field at a specific location on the background image.

I can code these by hand, but I would really like a GUI tool with field alignment tools and field properties.

If not in Orbeon, does anyone know of another tool?

Plan B would be to use a GUI form/field designer and then write code to generate the required HTML forms code.

Comment: What does your background image look like? One alternate suggestion would be to remove the field from the image but keep the rest of the image in tact and then you could position your fields were ever you want and not have to perfectly align them to the background image. This would depend on what your image looks like and if you could edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Orbeon Forms isn't really designed to create exact replicas on the web of paper forms. Because the web is such a different medium than paper, I think that in most cases it is better for the form author to rethink the form when adapting it for the web, even if only slightly so. Would it make sense to have a wizard? To leverage calculations? To have fields showing or not showing depending on other values?

If you need to create an exact copy of a paper form, with the positioning of the field matching exactly those in the paper version, as you said, you can do this positioning  with CSS, but Orbeon Forms doesn't really help you doing so.

Comment: The app we are using is an Open Source EMR (Electronic Medical Records).  Unfortunately, most of the other entities (hospitals, etc) we deal with want "their" forms filled out exactly. So we can't make any substitutions.  We have a javascript tool that generates the HTML forms code, but it's crude, compared to modern GUI design tools.

Comment: Do they just want the printed version to look exactly the same, or also the web form? We see the former a lot, e.g. with governments. And that case is supported, in the sense that you can attach a PDF to the form in Form Builder, and have it "filled out" with the values entered in the web form. So the web form has the same fields, but not necessarily position in a pixel-identical way relative to the PDF. Is this something that would help?

Comment: Getting there. I am assuming that the web form has to be mapped to the matching fields on the PDF.  Using a background image of the form and specifying X,Y field positions lets us do it in a single step. Generating a final PDF with Orbeon sounds interesting.    thanks